# How to catch nativeSms sendaction in my application in android

Tags: android

I am having an application in which i want to track the messages sent from native inbox.
i am using "android.intent.action.SEND" 
as intent filter in reciver of manifestfile.
But i am not able to catch it in onrecieve method..
Any ideas please help..
Thanks in advance